# Defend against Biotic Attack in Mass Effect 1

Tags: mass-effect

The most infuriating aspect of this game is a biotic attack. You get hit by one, and Shep goes all limp and starts rolling around on the floor, completely at the mercy of every assault rifle within a 30 mile perimeter.

Despite being a biotic, shielding myself with a biotic barrier and wearing light armour with biotic shielding I still find myself getting taken out constantly by a biotic attack.

Even when you're in cover biotic attacks can still hit you and cause you to 'collapse' out of cover.

I just don't really know how to stop them. I was a bastion and I was still getting hit by them. The Asari commandos when you face off Benezia on Noveria is a bit of a nightmare because of this.

How to I protect myself against this attack?

Comment: You know, I thought I could answer this, and then I realized I had no idea either, and had been just as frustrated at that stupid swooning thing as Starkers. So, I too would like to know how to avoid these, beyond blitzing biotics asap, which is obviously a pain in places like Noveria.

Comment: Are you sure cover doesn't prevent you from getting hit? I miss with Throw all the time because my enemy is behind something or simply because they moved from where I was aiming. Remember that just because you're pushed up against a source of cover doesn't mean you're untouchable. Bullets can still hit something behind cover if it isn't completely hidden.

Comment: @blaineh yeah but in video games cover should be cover IMHO :)

Comment: haha but realism man!!! If my answer about physics thresholds doesn't do the trick, just try to find better cover! ha

Comment: That's Neural Shock, and it's a tech ability, not biotic.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Armor Upgrade attribute [Physics Threshold](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Upgrades). Here's a description of the Exoskeleton upgrade:

> #### Exoskeleton
>
> Mechanical augmentation increases the force of rifle butts and other
>   melee attacks. The increased mass of the mechanized suit also provides
>   protection against high physics weapons and biotic attacks such as
>   Lift or Throw.

Or this excerpt from the [throw subsection of the Adept Guide](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Adept_Guide)

> Heavy objects and enemies with high physical force thresholds, like
>   krogan, will require a stronger push to be knocked down or moved.

Comment: Hey man, did this answer not work out?